# Why sqoop fails on NumberFormatException for numeric column during the export from hive to mysql

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have the simple hive query

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/tmp/test'
SELECT 
flight,
SUM(CASE WHEN ev=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS req 
from data_table
group by flight;
```

The output looks like ok (separated with ^A in editor) two numeric columns.
I've created mysql table

```
create table hive_table(fl int,evs int);
```

Finally I want to export the data from hdfs to mysql with sqoop

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://mysqlhost/dwh --username user --password password --table hive_table --export-dir /tmp/test/ --input-fields-terminated-by "\000" --lines-terminated-by '\n'
```

But I'm getting the following errors (although I see that the string is numeric value), and all export is fails. I just can't understand why?
I'm using cloudera cdh3

```
13/06/02 22:37:17 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/06/02 22:37:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201304210944_0692_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100322836692"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:458)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:554)
    at hive_table.__loadFromFields(hive_table.java:191)
    at hive_table.parse(hive_table.java:143)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:81)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:40)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:189)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformatio
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your MySQL table with a `BIGINT`, because some of your output like 100322836692 are too big to fit in an integer (from -2147483648 to 2147483648), so when Sqoop tries to import it will look at the schema, find that you're expecting an integer, try to parse the integer and then fail because it's too big.

This is expected when dealing with large amounts with Hive when you're doing `COUNT` or `SUM` I've seen a lot of time this error which is not always very explicit.

This should fix it:

```
create table hive_table(fl bigint, evs bigint);
```